# How to develop an aspx webpart for my SharePoint?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I´ve got a question!

I want to develop an aspx site for an sharepoint. I have Visual Studio and i cant find a way to develop an aspx page, only an asp.net core solution. Is this the same? Or what do i have to do, to get myself an aspx webpart i can upload to my sharepoint site?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Aspx files are part of ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) - Web Forms project type. So you must install .NetFramework if it doesn't show in project templates list.

[Here is how to create a project.](https://www.javatpoint.com/asp-net-web-form-project)

[Here is how to install .NetFramework in Visual Studio.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)